# How to display only the hovered label in plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to set the labelling such that only the value which is pointed by the cursor shows. Instead, the current code shows all y-values for any x-value.

```
library(plotly)
data_frame(noiseLevel=sort(rep(seq(10,50,10),5)),
           temperature=rep(seq(50,90,10),5),
           testScore=c(30,75,20,50,70,
                        40,60,45,20,50,
                        30,20,30,40,30,
                        60,30,60,20,50,
                        30,50,20,40,60)) -> dt

plot_ly(data=dt,
        x = noiseLevel,        
        y = testScore,
        color=factor(temperature),
        name = "linear", line = list(shape = "linear"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rld01 mentioned, this can be changed in the toolbar, but you can also change the default through R.  Here is the code.

```
library(plotly)
data.frame(noiseLevel=sort(rep(seq(10,50,10),5)),
           temperature=rep(seq(50,90,10),5),
           testScore=c(30,75,20,50,70,
                       40,60,45,20,50,
                       30,20,30,40,30,
                       60,30,60,20,50,
                       30,50,20,40,60)) -> dt

plot_ly(data=dt,
        x = noiseLevel,        
        y = testScore,
        color=factor(temperature),
        name = "linear", line = list(shape = "linear")) %>%
  layout(hovermode="closest")

# with upcoming plotly
# devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")
plot_ly(data=dt,
        x = ~noiseLevel,        
        y = ~testScore,
        color=~factor(temperature),
        name = "linear", line = list(shape = "linear")) %>%
  layout(hovermode="closest")
```